# Failed to connect to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I'm baffled, and am stuck, and have been for 2 hours now.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="yafnet" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Scirra;User Id=Gullanian;Password=12345;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I get:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Gullanian'.
```

I've created the database 'Scirra'.  I've also attempted to add a login, but nothing seems to work.  Logging into SQL management via Windows Authentication is the only way I can gain access to my DB's.

Ideally I just want to create a user, and that user having full control of DB.  So I can run scripts etc.

Here's a few details:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7600.16385
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     8.0.7600.16385
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.4952
Operating System                        6.1.7600
```

Idk why it says v2 for asp.net, all my application pools are set to 4.0.

Comment: When you look in the SQL Server logs what reason does it say for the login failed?

Comment: @martin Login failed for user 'Gullanian'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: You need to enable SQL Server authentication then (will need a restart) or use Windows Auth.

Comment: @Martin, FIXED THANKS!  Changed auth mode to mixed :D  If you add it in an answer ill give u rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable SQL Server authentication (will need a restart) or use Windows Authentication.